# Post multiple input fields in Rails as a List instead of with individual names.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb, form-for

I would like to submit a list to the controller with a `form_for`. This list should be populated with `text_field`s.

This implementation will submit `:some_list` with the value of only one text_field in the list (as expected). I want X amount of `text_field`s to be submitted as a list, since the number of text fields is dynamic, as to receive something of the sort: `params {..."name":"Something", "some_list":["a", "b"]}` or some JSON equivalent.

## .erb

```
<%= form_for @my_model do |f|%>
  <% f.text_field :name %>

  <% (0...@some_limit).each do |index| %>
    <%= f.text_field :some_list %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

### The Model

Note the Model is not an ActiveRecord

```
class MyModel

  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :name, :some_list

  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates :some_list, :presence => true

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `multiple: true` with text_field name.

```
<%= form_for @my_model do |f|%>
  <% f.text_field :name %>

  <% (0...@some_limit).each do |index| %>
    <%= f.text_field :some_list, multiple: true %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Error: `undefined method 'some_list[]' ... Did you mean?  some_list `. Is there any change needed to the Model for this to work ?

Comment: @erielmarimon Hi , Just add `multiple: true` it will work, as `<%= f.text_field :some_list, multiple: true %>`

Answer (score 2):

You can you use text_field_tag like this,

```
<% (0...@some_limit).each do |index| %>
  <%= text_field_tag "#{f.object.class.to_s.underscore}[some_list][]" %>
<% end %>
```

This is a kind of a hack, The accepted answer is the appropriate solution.

Comment: It won't warp `some_field` data with form_for submitted data, instead you will get this as individual.

Comment: @Gabbar correct, this works but is not specific for the form for. As selected,  `<%= f.text_field :some_list, multiple: true %>` is a more accurate implementation.

Comment: @Gabbar updated the answer. now it will work as you expected

Comment: @AbhilashReddy Great!, but isn't `multiple: true` is smart way with `f.text_field` instead of `text_field_tag` ?

Comment: @Gabbar yes agreed, also mentioned the same thing in my answer. Just wanted to show my solution, so that it might help someone understand on how to submit an array.

Comment: @AbhilashReddy Appreciated ! :)

Comment: Worked quite well when I needed to use this for some hidden fields that acted as a list.