# RAILS 6 - How to post multiple model objects in one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I want to build a form thats able to handle multiple instances of the same object, the same model.

Somethink like :

```
<%= form_with(model: Person.new) do |f| %>
...
<%= loop ....
   <%= f.text_field(:first_name) %>   
   ...
   <%= f.text_field(:last_name) %>   
   ...
<% end loop ....
```

-> Then the controller should now be able to create multiple objects from the same Person object.

How works that ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51167201/post-multiple-input-fields-in-rails-as-a-list-instead-of-with-individual-names maybe this can help

Comment: Rails does not have a built in way to create multiple models in a form if they are not wrapped by a another model and you use `accepts_nested_attributes`. The best solution is to not use a single form but multiple forms and use ajax to make it appear seamless to the user.

Comment: Its far simpler since you're just making ajax calls to a normal rails CRUD controller and you don't have to deal with binding multiple for inputs to multiple records and handle the chaos of transactions and validating n number of records.

Comment: Hi max, do you have a link to a piblic site where this approach is explained ?